# Issues avoiding division by zero in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
    A  B
0   2  8
1   3  1
2   5  0
3  -1  2
4   2  1
5   3  0
.. .. ..
```

I want to calculate `((df['B']-df['A'])/df['B'])*100` in a new column so i did this code to avoid division by zero:

```
if data['B']!=0:
   data['D%']=((data['B']-data['A'])/data['B'])*100
else:
   data['D%']=np.nan
```

But i got this error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Would you mind to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data['B'] != 0' is actually comparing the whole column `[8, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0] != 0` which evaluates to `[True, True, False, True, True, False]`. The `if` statement is looking for a condition that is simply either `True` or `False`, which is why you get the `ValueError`. The solutions below are good, but just wanted to explain why you got that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test a vector/list/Series (`df['B']`) to a scalar value (`0`) because Python doesn't know how to handle it. How to interpret `[8, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0] != 0`?

You can mask values:

```
df['D%'] = ((df['B']-df['A'])/df['B'].mask(df['B'].eq(0)))*100

# Or

df['D%'] = ((df['B']-df['A'])/df['B'].replace(0, np.nan))*100

# Or

df['D%'] = (((df['B']-df['A'])/df['B'])*100).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   A  B     D%
0  2  8   75.0
1  3  1 -200.0
2  5  0    NaN
3 -1  2  150.0
4  2  1 -100.0
5  3  0    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.Series.div` method, it handles zeroes and NaNs:

```
(df['B'] - df['A']).div(df['B']) * 100
```

Output:

```
0     75.0
1   -200.0
2     -inf
3    150.0
4   -100.0
5     -inf
dtype: float64
```

Or try and negate `df.pct_change(-1, axis=1)`.

Comment: Dividing by 0 or NaN is supported with `/` operator but returns `np.inf`. What I understand is OP want to replace them by NaN?